Laravel blade pass jquery function
searchJS.blade.php
$(document).ready(function () {  
  function deleteData(firstNo,secondNo){
    console.log(firstNo)
    console.log(secondNo)
  }

  num = 111
  num2 = 222

  btnGroup += `<button type='button' class="mx-3 btn btn-danger" onclick="${deleteData(num, num2)}">Delete</button>`

}

Originally the btnGroup is already displaying on Laravel blade and actually I had 2 parameters to be passed into the onclick function but I have a difficulty that the onclick function could not be recognized while clicking the button so how should I modify the code to have the onclick function readable?
I tried to modify the code and the solution still not working properly

This code doesn't do anything. Please [edit] your question to contain a [mre] and explain the difference between what you expect it to do and what it actually does

Injecting values into onclick attributes is usually troublesome. Instead, add attributes or properties to your elements that can be read from a generic event handler.
For example
// Add a delegated event listener
$(document).on('click', 'button.btn-danger', function (e) {
  const { val1, val2 } = $(this).data();
  console.log(val1, val2);
});

const btnGroup = [];

// ...and when creating a button

btnGroup.push($('<button>', {
  class: 'mx-3 btn btn-danger',
  type: 'button',
  text: 'Delete',
  'data-val1': 111,
  'data-val2': 222,
}));

// ...then append the array somewhere

$('#some-parent-element').append(btnGroup);


The same can be accomplished without jQuery in about as many lines
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const btn = e.target.closest('button.btn-danger');
  if (btn) {
    const { val1, val2 } = btn.dataset;
    console.log(val1, val2);
  }
});

const btnGroup = [];

// ...and when creating a button

const btn = Object.assign(document.createElement('button'), {
  className: 'mx-3 btn btn-danger',
  type: 'button',
  textContent: 'Delete',
});
btn.dataset.val1 = 111;
btn.dataset.val2 = 222;
btnGroup.push(btn);

// ...then append the array somewhere

document.getElementById('some-parent-element').append(...btnGroup);


Originally btnGroup has some values and I would like to append the value to it

@MERNStackDeveloper then make it an array

In actual I have two parameters to be passed in so how to use Object.assign to pass?

You didn't think that was important to mention in your original question?

Sorry I forgot to mention as just now would like to at least could recognize the first parameter

I've updated my answer to account for all the changes introduced in your question
